# In pandas/python, how can I quickly label each row with the period it belongs to while removing those that don't fit any periods

Tags: pandas, performance, datetime, dataset

I have a large dataset where one column is datetimes. I also have a smaller dataset with ranges that I'm interested in. I want to remove all rows in the large dataset where the datetimes do not fall in my ranges of interest, and I want to label all rows that are in one of the periods with the period to which they belong.
I know that there are similar questions on here, but those I could find had continuous ranges so that cut could be used. My end-times do not match the start-times of the next periods, so I don't see how I could use that.

To make it even more difficult, I found that the ranges that I was given actually do not always match up completely with reality, so I want to also retrieve rows just outside of the given periods. To do this, I created 'fuzzy' start and end times by adding/subtracting a certain amount of time. Sadly, there's a few times where the fuzzy start of one period overlaps with the fuzzy end of the previous one. When this happens, I want to label the row for whichever period is closest.

Example dataframes of what I mean (my real data has datetime not just dates):

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2015-02-01', '2015-03-02', '2015-03-15', '2015-03-04', '2015-04-17', '2015-05-12', '2015-02-14', '2015-04-14'],
                     'expected_period': ['One', 'Two', 'Two', 'Two', 'Four', np.NAN, np.NAN, 'Three'],
                     'expected_certainty': ['Given', 'Given', 'Fuzzy', 'Given', 'Given', np.NAN, np.NAN, 'Fuzzy']})

dfb = pd.DataFrame({'Period': ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'],
                    'Fuzzy Start Dates': ['2015-01-01', '2015-02-15', '2015-03-14', '2015-04-14'],
                    'Given Start Dates': ['2015-01-03', '2015-02-17', '2015-03-16', '2015-04-16'],
                    'Given End Dates': ['2015-02-11', '2015-03-10', '2015-04-13', '2015-05-08'],
                    'Fuzzy End Dates': ['2015-02-13', '2015-03-12', '2015-04-15', '2015-05-10']})
```

I have the following code, which does work, but it is very slow and I feel like there is probably a much better way to go about it than slicing a copy of dfb multiple times for each row in the large dataset. I can imagine it might be possible with groupby but I haven't been able to make that work.

```
def determine_period(datetime, periods):
    df = periods[(periods['Fuzzy Start Dates'] <= datetime) & (periods['Fuzzy End Dates'] >= datetime)]
    ndf = df[(df['Given Start Dates'] <= datetime) & (df['Given End Dates'] >= datetime)]
    if len(ndf) == 1:  # high certainty, datetime within given boundaries
        return {'period': ndf['Period'].iloc[0], 'certainty': 'Given'}

    elif len(df) == 0:  # not inside any periods, to be removed
        return {'period': np.nan, 'certainty': np.nan}

    elif len(df) == 1:  # in fuzzy area of one period
        return {'period': df['Period'].iloc[0], 'certainty': 'Fuzzy'}

    else:  # in fuzzy area of two periods, choose nearest
        df['diff_start'] = abs(df['Given Start Dates'] - datetime)
        df['diff_end'] = abs(df['Given End Dates'] - datetime)
        df['diff'] = df[['diff_start', 'diff_end']].min(axis=1)
        return {'period': df['Period'].loc[df['diff'].idxmin()], 'certainty': 'Fuzzy'}

dfa['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfa['datetime']) # All dates in dfb are already datetimes in my code
temp = dfa.apply(lambda x: determine_period(x.datetime, dfb), axis=1, result_type="expand")
dfa = pd.concat([dfa, temp], axis='columns')
dfa.dropna(subset=['period'], inplace=True)
```